# Network Printer Connection Using POE Switch

Tags: electrical-power, network-printer

Is there any problem connecting a network printer to a POE switch?

Comment: Are you wanting to power the printer with PoE, or just use it normally?

Comment: Just to use it normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in my experience no.

Comment: What are the problems with it?

Comment: None, that's why I said no...

Comment: Ah - thanks for that. I'm having a brain fade day...

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to worry about powering non compliant
devices ,such as Printers, Fax machines or PC’s because
these devices do not carry the IEEE802.3af signature,
thus the ports will automatically disable power.